# Laravel updating the list/sort order in the database is also updating the id

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, drag-and-drop, eloquent

I'm using drag and drop on the front-end which calls a Laravel (5.3) API to update the database. This works OK, except I noticed this method also changes the `id` of that item. Some of my other sortable Models use Polymorphic relationships which break when I use the code below.

```
public function sort(SocialMediaItemRequest $request)
{
    $icons = Auth::user()->socialmediaicons;

    $icons->each(function ($icon, $index) use ($request) {
        $icon->update($request->icons[$index], ['list_order' => $icon->list_order]);
    });

    return fractal()->collection($icons, new SocialMediaIconsTransformer())->toArray();
}
```

I also tried

```
$icons->each(function ($icon) use ($request) {
    $icon->update(['order' => $request->order]);
});
```

But this doesn't work either. All I want to so is change the `list_order` fields associated with `user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some help on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/69g6y0/updating_the_listsort_order_in_the_database_is/) and this is the final solution I'm using:

```
public function sort(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->icons as $icon) {
        SocialMediaIcon::where('id', $icon['id'])->update(['list_order' => $icon['list_order']]);
    }

    return fractal()->collection(Auth::user()->socialmediaicons, new SocialMediaIconsTransformer())->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works. But I'm open to other suggestions:

```
public function sort(SocialMediaItemRequest $request)
{
    foreach (($request->icons) as $icon => $id) {
        SocialMediaIcon::where('id', $id)->update([
            'list_order' => $icon + 1
        ]);
    }

    $icons = Auth::user()->socialmediaicons;
    return fractal()->collection($icons, new SocialMediaIconsTransformer())->toArray();
}
```